# BeautifulSoup Scraping Formatting

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my first time using `BeautifulSoup` and I am attempting to scrap store location data from a local convenience store.

However I'm running into some issues on trying to remove empty lines when data is being passed into a CSV file, I've tried `.replace('\n','')` and `.strip()` both did not worked.

Also I'm having problems with splitting data that is scraped and contained in the same sibling method.

I've added the script below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import urllib.request
import sched, time
import csv

url = 'http://www.cheers.com.sg/web/store_location.jsp'

response = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
#print (soup.prettify())

#open a file for writing
location_data = open('data/soupdata.csv', 'w', newline='')

#create the csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(location_data)

cheers = soup.find('div' , id="store_container")

count = 0

#Loop for Header tags
for paragraph in cheers.find_all('b'):

    header1 = paragraph.text.replace(':' , '')
    header2 = paragraph.find_next('b').text.replace(':' , '')
    header3 = paragraph.find_next_siblings('b')[1].text.replace(':' , '')
    if count == 0:      
        csvwriter.writerow([header1, header2, header3])
        count += 1

    break

for paragraph in cheers.find_all('br'): 
    brnext = paragraph.next_sibling.strip()
    brnext1 = paragraph.next_sibling
    test1 = brnext1.next_sibling.next_sibling

    print(test1)
    csvwriter.writerow([brnext, test1])

location_data.close()
```

Sample of output generated:

[image: Sample of output generated]

Sample of what output should look like:

[image: Sample of what output should look like]

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You just need to change the way of extracting address, tel and store hours**

```
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = 'http://www.cheers.com.sg/web/store_location.jsp'

response = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
# print (soup.prettify())

# open a file for writing
location_data = open('data/soupdata.csv', 'w', newline='')

# create the csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(location_data)

cheers = soup.find('div', id="store_container")

count = 0

# Loop for Header tags
for paragraph in cheers.find_all('b'):
    header1 = paragraph.text.replace(':', '')
    header2 = paragraph.find_next('b').text.replace(':', '')
    header3 = paragraph.find_next_siblings('b')[1].text.replace(':', '')
    if count == 0:
        csvwriter.writerow([header1, header2, header3])
        count += 1

    break

for paragraph in cheers.find_all('div'):
    label = paragraph.find_all('b')
    if len(label) == 3:
        print(label)
        address = label[0].next_sibling.next_sibling
        tel = label[1].next_sibling
        hours = label[2].next_sibling
        csvwriter.writerow([address, tel, hours])

location_data.close()
```

Comment: This works perfectly was stuck on this for hours. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

To make it slightly organized, you can try like the following. I've used [.select()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead of [.find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all).

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.cheers.com.sg/web/store_location.jsp'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
with open("output.csv","w",newline="") as infile:
    writer = csv.writer(infile)
    writer.writerow(["Address","Telephone","Store hours"])

    for items in soup.select("#store_container .store_col"): 
        addr = items.select_one("b").next_sibling.next_sibling
        tel = items.select_one("b:nth-of-type(2)").next_sibling
        store = items.select_one("b:nth-of-type(3)").next_sibling
        writer.writerow([addr,tel,store])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help as well, appreciate it. Also just wondering, is there a way to create a script that could scrape multiple sites with different structures autonomously?. Would be a pain to create a individual script just for a single site.

Comment: When html structures are different, your script should be different as well otherwise a script meant to be created for one site will fail miserably when applied on others. However, there is still some hope. Take a look at this [Natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing)

Comment: Figures as much thought that it would need to require some sort of processing with AI to actually do autonomous scraping. Haha. Just that its going to take me awhile to learn how to use beautifulsoup on other sites. Too troublesome to ask again on this platform